# Relatório em mPDF só retornar um unico registro ao receber dados via POST

Tags: php, mpdf

Estou tentando gerar um PDF com dados enviados via POST.
[inserir a descrição do link aqui](https://gist.github.com/FabricioYwin/843377a186cc083887110bef057f007d)

O arquivo os-lista.php é um relatório que os dados mudam de acordo com o filtro.
Eu estou enviando esses dados mas só aparece o ultimo registro.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seus inputs tem `names` repetidos em cada linha

```
<input type="hidden" name="OSid" value="<?=$OSid?>" />
```

Nesse caso quando você enviar o POST o navegador vai enviar somente o último valor lido, os últimos names da página.

Se você fizer os names como `arrays`:

```
<input type="hidden" name="OSid[]" value="<?=$OSid?>" />
```

O `$_POST['OSid']` vai ser uma lista de todos os ids enviados, e assim com todos os `names`.

**EDIT acrescentando implementação**

Para gerar o relatório com várias linhas:

```
<?php
    // Cada um desses valores agora é um array
     $OSid          = $_POST['OSid'];
     $dataHora      = $_POST['dataHora'];
     $nomeFantasia  = $_POST['nomeFantasia'];
     $NomeSetor     = $_POST['NomeSetor'];
     $motivoOs      = $_POST['motivoOs'];
     $TotalMaterial = $_POST['TotalMaterial'];
     $NomeTipoOS    = $_POST['NomeTipoOS'];
     $status        = $_POST['status'];



     $corpo_pagina = "

    <html>
        <head>
            <link href='css/bootstrap.css' media='print' rel='stylesheet'>
            <link href='css/estiloOS.css' media='print' rel='stylesheet' >
        </head>   
    <boby>
        <table border='1' class='table table-striped'>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>DATA</th>
                <th>CLIENTE</th>
                <th>SETOR</th>       
                <th>MOTIVOS OS</th>
                <th>CUSTO TOTAL</th>
                <th>TIPO OS</th>
                <th>STATUS</th>
            </tr>";

            // Fazemos um laço pelo número de itens da lista
            // $OSid e imprimimos cada item em uma linha separada
            for( $i = 0; $i < count( $OSid ); $i++ ) {
                $corpo_pagina .= "
                    <tr>
                        <td>".$OSid[$i]."</td>
                        <td>".$dataHora[$i]."</td>
                        <td>".$nomeFantasia[$i]."</td>
                        <td>".$NomeSetor[$i]."</td>
                        <td>".$motivoOs[$i]."</td>
                        <td>".$TotalMaterial[$i]."</td>
                        <td>".$NomeTipoOS[$i]."</td>    
                        <td>".$status[$i]."</td>
                    </tr>";
            }

        $corpo_pagina .= "</table>";
```

Comment: Não nada de errado ai nesse array, não.
Está retornando a palavra array em todos eles.

Comment: Você deve ter que alterar a forma como os dados são inseridos na tabela. Se você só usa `echo` ou `print` ele imprime `Array`. Agora você precisa referenciar as chaves pra imprimir o valor correto. Ex.: https://eval.in/680884

Comment: <td><?php
            $OSid = array();
            $OSid[] = $os['id'];
            foreach($OSid as $valor_OSid):
                print_r($valor_OSid ); ?>
        <input type="hidden" name="OSid[]" value="<?=$valor_OSid?>" />
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </td>

Está exibindo na lista mas o pdf só aparece a palavra array.
Obrigado.

Comment: editei a resposta acrescentando a implementação na saída do relatório. O código que você está mostrando acredito que é o da tabela na tela, mas o princípio é o mesmo.

Comment: Eu fiz as alterações mas está dando erro ao gerar documento PDF.
Atualizei o Gits.  
Você disse que o value é `value="<?=$OSid?>"`
É isso mesmo?  
Pq é o `foreach($OSid as $valor_OSid):`
Não seria o `value="<?=$valor_OSid?>"`   ?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/FabricioYwin/843377a186cc083887110bef057f007d

Comment: qual erro está dando?

Comment: Falha ao Gerar documento PDF.  
Recarregar?  
Ai se clicar, nada acontece.

Comment: Olha o print, pfv.
http://imgur.com/a/Mgx5U

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48804/discussion-between-ricardo-moraleida-and-fabricio-wm).